# How to get password from jboss database configuration

Tags: java, database, configuration, jboss

My problem is that I have configured a oracle-ds.xml in jboss deploy folder. I can get the instance of dataSource and connection. And now, I want to get the password from the database configuration through jboss api. What could I do at the moment?
Database Configuration:

```
<datasources>
  <xa-datasource>
    <jndi-name>XPCDataSource</jndi-name>
    <track-connection-by-tx/>
    <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.17.16.49:1521:ora49</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="User">workbench_0628</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">workbench_0628</xa-datasource-property>
    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- Oracles XA datasource cannot reuse a connection outside a transaction once enlisted in a global transaction and vice-versa -->
    <no-tx-separate-pools/>
    <metadata>
      <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </xa-datasource>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleXAExceptionFormatter" name="jboss.jca:service=OracleXAExceptionFormatter">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="TransactionManagerService">jboss:service=TransactionManager</depends>
  </mbean>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
   Connection conn = myJBossDatasource.getConnection();
   WrappedConnection wrappedConn = (WrappedConnection)conn;
   Connection underlyingConn = wrappedConn.getUnderlyingConnection();
   OracleConnection oracleConn = (OracleConnection)underlyingConn;
```

I've primarily used BEA/Oracle (Weblogic) but did this a LONG time ago...  If you check out the OracleConnection object it has some constants:

```
   CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD
   CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME
```

- SEE: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html  (JavaDoc)

Comment: I've read the OracleConnection API, tried as above and got the OracleConnection instance correctly. 
But it's impossible to get the username and the password by constants of CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD and CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME, because CONNECTION_PROPERTY_PASSWORD and CONNECTION_PROPERTY_USER_NAME are inexistent in the source code of oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection(Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0", ojdbc14.jar). 
>Also, I couldn't find the password in properties by invoking oracleConn.getConnectionAttributes() and oracleConn.getProperties().